# How to increase speed of depositing values onto a large 3d grid

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, voxel

I have a large set of data points in 3 column vectors. There are 10 million points with x,y,z coordinates.

I am voxelizing these points (assigning them to a discrete grid based upon occupancy). There are two ways to accomplish voxelization. The first way being a simple binning procedure where if the point falls within a certain bin that bin's intensity increases by 1. The other way is to assign a point to multiple bins and increase intensity based on distance from the bin centers. I wish to accomplish the second method of voxelization.

A simple 2d example of this is:
Say you have point x,y=1.7,2.2
And have an evenly spaced grid with distance .5 between nodes in x and y.

Using method 1:
The point would get binned to x,y=1.5,2 with intensity=1

Using method 2:
The point would get distributed to (x,y),(x-.5,y),(x+.5,y),(x,y-.5),(x,y+.5)
With intensities=(distTOpoint1/sumDistances),(distTopoint2/sumDistances),...,(distTopoint5/sumDistances)

```
def floorPartial (value, resolution):
    return np.floor (value / resolution) * resolution 

def EucDistSq(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2):
        return (x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2+(z1-z2)**2

xCoord=100*np.random.random(10000000)
yCoordC=100*np.random.random(10000000)
zCoord=100*np.random.random(10000000)

Xspacing=.1
Yspacing=.1
zspacing=.1
Grid=np.empty([len(xCoord),8,4])

for i in range(len(xCoord)):

    Grid[i,0,:]=[xCoord[i],yCoordC[i],zCoord[i],0] #Save original Point

    #calculate voxel which it would go to if it was simple binning
    vX=floorPartial(xCoord[i],Xspacing) 
    vY=floorPartial(yCoordC[i],Yspacing)
    vZ=floorPartial(zCoord[i],Zspacing)


    d1=EucDistSq(xCoord[i],yCoordC[i],zCoord[i],vX,vY,vZ)
    d2=EucDistSq(xCoord[i],yCoordC[i],zCoord[i],vX+Xspacing,vY,vZ)
    d3=EucDistSq(xCoord[i],yCoordC[i],zCoord[i],vX-Xspacing,vY,vZ)
    d4=EucDistSq(xCoord[i],yCoordC[i],zCoord[i],vX,vY+Yspacing,vZ)
    d5=EucDistSq(xCoord[i],yCoordC[i],zCoord[i],vX,vY-Yspacing,vZ)
    d6=EucDistSq(xCoord[i],yCoordC[i],zCoord[i],vX,vY,vZ+Zspacing)
    d7=EucDistSq(xCoord[i],yCoordC[i],zCoord[i],vX,vY,vZ-Zspacing)

    dt=np.sum([d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7])

    #VoxelX,VoxelY,VoxelZ,intensity
    Grid[i,1,:]=[vX,vY,vZ,d1/dt]
    Grid[i,2,:]=[vX+Xspacing,vY,vZ,d2/dt]
    Grid[i,3,:]=[vX-Xspacing,vY,vZ,d3/dt]
    Grid[i,4,:]=[vX,vY+Yspacing,vZ,d4/dt]
    Grid[i,5,:]=[vX,vY-Yspacing,vZ,d5/dt]
    Grid[i,6,:]=[vX,vY,vZ+Zspacing,d6/dt]
    Grid[i,7,:]=[vX,vY,vZ-Zspacing,d7/dt]
```

Then after this I plan to retrace through this giant array and add all of these intensities up for the same points to get my final map, but this really does not matter at the moment.

This code works to voxelize the 3d points but it is super slow. Is there a way to do this less naively and faster? I was thinking create a grid beforehand with coordinates and intensity of 0 at each point and in a loop update the intensity with += or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to remove for loop and use numpy operations to take a care of it. Same code as yours without for loop and indexing is ~60x faster:

```
def ver_2(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, xSpacing, ySpacing, zSpacing):
    Grid = numpy.empty([len(xCoord), 8, 4])
    Grid[:, 0, 0] = xCoord
    Grid[:, 0, 1] = yCoord
    Grid[:, 0, 2] = zCoord
    Grid[:, 0, 3] = 0
    #
    vX = floorPartial(xCoord, xSpacing)
    vY = floorPartial(yCoord, ySpacing)
    vZ = floorPartial(zCoord, zSpacing)
    #
    d1 = EucDistSq(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, vX, vY, vZ)
    d2 = EucDistSq(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, vX+xSpacing, vY, vZ)
    d3 = EucDistSq(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, vX-xSpacing, vY, vZ)
    d4 = EucDistSq(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, vX, vY+ySpacing, vZ)
    d5 = EucDistSq(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, vX, vY-ySpacing, vZ)
    d6 = EucDistSq(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, vX, vY, vZ+zSpacing)
    d7 = EucDistSq(xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, vX, vY, vZ-zSpacing)
    #
    dt = numpy.sum([d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7], axis=0)
    # VoxelX,VoxelY,VoxelZ,intensity
    Grid[:, 1] = numpy.stack((vX, vY, vZ, d1/dt), axis=-1)
    Grid[:, 2] = numpy.stack((vX+xSpacing, vY, vZ, d2/dt), axis=-1)
    Grid[:, 3] = numpy.stack((vX-xSpacing, vY, vZ, d3/dt), axis=-1)
    Grid[:, 4] = numpy.stack((vX, vY+ySpacing, vZ, d4/dt), axis=-1)
    Grid[:, 5] = numpy.stack((vX, vY-ySpacing, vZ, d5/dt), axis=-1)
    Grid[:, 6] = numpy.stack((vX, vY, vZ+zSpacing, d6/dt), axis=-1)
    Grid[:, 7] = numpy.stack((vX, vY, vZ-zSpacing, d7/dt), axis=-1)
    return Grid
```

I suppose the some more optimization is possible with more matrix oriented calculation, but I didn't grasp exactly what code has to do :-/ Probably setting Grid's [:, 1-7, 0-2] values before calculation of distance, and than using only Grid values for distance calculation can reduce some time because of omitting some not needed allocations.

Comment: This vectorization is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for the idea